# Can't generate drop down menu with Materialize CSS framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

Docs: http://materializecss.link/dropdown.html

```
<!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
<a class="dropdown-button btn" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Drop Me!</a>

<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul style="width: 138px; display: none; top: 283.317px; left: 454px; height: 159px; opacity: 0;" id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Apparently this is all you need to get this working. What on earth am I missing?

**Update:**

This is all at the bottom of my page:

```
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Materialize -->
  <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
  <script src="js/init.js"></script>

  <!-- Javascript -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.19.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.js"></script>
  <script src="js/blog.js"></script>

  <!-- Popup -->

  <script src="view.min.js?auto"></script>
```

... and this is in my header at the top:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
        inDuration: 300,
        outDuration: 225,
      constrain_width: false, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
      hover: false, // Activate on click
      alignment: 'left', // Aligns dropdown to left or right edge (works with constrain_width)
      gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
      belowOrigin: false // Displays dropdown below the button
    }
    );
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Check this source: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/dropdown.html Learn how this dropdown work.

Comment: Looks identical to the code I provided.

Comment: Yes it is, this is weird.

Comment: Here the solution: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1145 Tested: https://jsfiddle.net/Ferrrmolina/m6fvmy6d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Code below might explain the structure of the HTML file a little bit better. You can put all of the scripts and script references in the `HEAD`.

Also have a look at this page, where you will find further information of using the different types of implementing JavaScript in your page.

http://javascript.info/tutorial/adding-script-html

```html
<html> 
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <!-- This script block could also be in an external .js file -->
    <!-- <script src="js/your_custom_js.js"></script> -->
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
              inDuration: 300,
              outDuration: 225,
              constrain_width: false, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
              hover: false, // Activate on click
              alignment: 'left', // Aligns dropdown to left or right edge (works with constrain_width)
              gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
              belowOrigin: false // Displays dropdown below the button
            });
        });
    </script>
    <!-- This script block could also be in an external .js file -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
  <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>
  <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
  <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
  </ul>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this in a fresh project and it worked. I cleaned up all my JavaScript includes, etc. but that still didn't do anything. As it stands, it does not work in my project but I believe that is because of an unrelated problem regarding how I template my website with handlebars.js. Cheers, and thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can help you out?
Include jQuery, materialize.js, materialize.css and do the jQuery Plugin Initialization when the Document is ready:

See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Also important I think is the order of the JavaScript files. 
First load jQuery then the materialize.js

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
      inDuration: 300,
      outDuration: 225,
      constrain_width: false, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
      hover: false, // Activate on click
      alignment: 'left', // Aligns dropdown to left or right edge (works with constrain_width)
      gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
      belowOrigin: false // Displays dropdown below the button
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<html> 
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
  <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>
  <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
  <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
  </ul>
</html>
```

Comment: Do I explicitly include that jquery script on my page?

Comment: The jQuery Snippet should be included in your page yes. You could put it directly in the `<head>` within a `<script>`Tag or inlude it as a sinle external .js file. Your script should be loaded as the last JavaScript in your page.  First jquery.min.js, Second materialize.min.js, Third yourCustom.js.

Comment: Hmm... I can't get it to work. I've updated my question to show how my scripts are included.

Comment: Ok wow you´ve got a lot of JavaScript files, and some of them are redundant. 1) You do not have to implement the same JavaScript files twice, e.g.: `materialize.min.js` and `materialize.js`. The `min.js` is just the compressed version with less file size. 2) When you use relative paths like `js/materialize.js`check if the path is correct and the files are loaded. Look into your network traffic in the developer toolbar if you get and 404 error. 3) To use your custom script on every page, put it in a .js file and also reference it like: `<script src="js/your_custom_script.js"></script>`